# Getting error to import Spring boot parent into Pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to create a sample Spring-Boot project using maven but when i imported into Eclipse. I am getting an error in Pom.xml about spring-boot parent but when i run mvn command from terminal. It works fine. Also, in main class, it does not recognize org.springframework.*

I am getting an error which says that

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.3.0.RELEASE from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.3.0.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.0.RELEASE.pom. Error code 501, HTTPS Required and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

My Pom.xml looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- <relativePath /> -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>products</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>products</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding repository in pom.xml. Also make sure you have proper internet connection so that dependencies will get downloaded from repo.

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Error code 501, HTTPS Required` - this error indicates that you are trying to connect to maven central repository using `HTTP` protocol

From beginning of 2020, maven central supports communication over `HTTPS` only. See [this page](https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https) for more details

Verify your maven settings. If you have configured maven central repository with http urls `http://repo1.maven.org` or `http://repo.maven.apache.org/` switch url to `https`